# How can I retrieve the timestamp of a video frame as it's being recorded?

Tags: android

So I've been trying to figure out a way to get the timestamp of a video frame as it's being recorded.

All of the samples online and in the API documentation tell you to use MediaRecorder to record video from the camera. The problem is that no timestamp data is returned, nor is there a callback called when it records a frame.

I started investigating the Camera app in the Android 4.2 source code, and was able to make significant progress on this. I successfully recorded video from the camera, saving frame timestamps to a file when the SurfaceTexture's onFrameAvailable listener was called, since SurfaceTexture has a timestamp property.

Upon further investigation though, I figured out that I was receiving these callbacks when the frame was being *displayed* not when *recorded*. In hindsight, this makes a lot of sense and I should have spotted it earlier.

In any case, I continued further into the Camera app and started looking at the EffectsRecorder class that it has. I found that it uses some undocumented APIs via the filter framework to allow the use of OpenGL shaders. For my use case, this is helpful, so I likely will continue down this path. I'm still trying to make my way through it to get it recording video correctly, but I feel like I will still only get timestamps on display, rather than on recording.

Looking further, I see that it uses a filter that has a MediaRecorder class underneath it, using an undocumented second video source other than camera called GRALLOC_BUFFER = 2. This is even more intriguing and useful, but ultimately, I still need the timestamp for the frame being recorded.

I'm appealing to Stack Overflow in hopes that someone in the community has encountered this. I simply need a pointer of where to look. I can provide source code, since most of it is just lifted from the AOSP, but I haven't as yet simply because I'm not sure what would be relevant.

Help is greatly appreciated.